# How to update dataframes each time a new date is passed

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am building a dashboard that generates a report based on the input dates. 5 csv's are generated as part of the report, which are displayed on drop down approach and made downloadable. The problem is the dataframes which are are reading the csv's are not getting updated once a new report is generated. It still holds data of the last run. How do i fix the same?

````
from kontekst_report_server_datewise import kontekst


def generate_table(dataframe,max_rows=10):
    return html.Table(
        # Header
        [html.Tr([html.Th(col) for col in dataframe.columns])] +

        # Body
        [html.Tr([
            html.Td(dataframe.iloc[i][col]) for col in dataframe.columns
        ]) for i in range(min(len(dataframe), max_rows))]
    )


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
# external_stylesheets = ['https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css']


app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.DatePickerRange(id='date-picker-range',
                                         start_date=datetime(2019, 4, 3), end_date=datetime(2019, 4, 4)),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='my-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label' : 'Returns Summary' , 'value' : 'df1'},
            {'label' : 'Return Guide Doc Details' , 'value' : 'df2'},
            {'label' : 'Return Guide id Counts' , 'value' : 'df3'},
            {'label' : 'Non Return Guide id Counts', 'value' : 'df4'},
            {'label' : 'Order Creation Details' , 'value' : 'df5'}
        ],
        # value='df1'
        # multi = True
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-container'),
    html.A('Download CSV', id = 'my-link'),
    html.Div(id='kontekst')
])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-container', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    df1 = pd.read_csv('returns_summary.csv')
    df2 = pd.read_csv('ReturnGuideDocDetails.csv')
    df3 = pd.read_csv('Return_guideid_counts.csv')
    df4 = pd.read_csv('NonReturn_guideid_counts.csv')
    df5 = pd.read_csv('OrderCreationdetails.csv')

    if value == 'df1':
        return generate_table(df1)
    elif value == 'df2':
        return generate_table(df2)
    elif value == 'df3' :
        return generate_table(df3)
    elif value == 'df4' :
        return generate_table(df4)
    elif value == 'df5' :
        return generate_table(df5)


@app.callback(Output('my-link', 'href'), [Input('my-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_link(value):
    return '/dash/urlToDownload?value={}'.format(value)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)```
````

Comment: You have 5 hard-coded dataframes being created from CSV files here. How are those supposed to change?

Comment: Please specify what you expect to change and where it is supposed to change. As @coralvanda mentions there is no place in your code that changes the underlying data.